# Triple Integral on the xy-plane

Tags: calculus, integration

For the solid bounded by $x=0 , x=2, z=y, z=y-1, z=0, z=4$ I am looking at the $xy-plane$ and setting up a triple integral. I'm not sure where to start on this problem, as some of the plans are "$z=$" but I know $z=0$ is the xy-plane. I think I may need two integrals here. I get $\int_{0}^{2} \int_{z}^{z+1} \int_{y-1}^{y} dzdydx$ and $\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{4} \int_{y-1}^{y} dzdydx$. Not sure if this is correct however since the volume together would be 10 and for the yz plane I got 8 and they are supposed to be the same. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int_0^2\int_0^4\int_z^{z+1}dydzdx=8=\displaystyle \int_0^4\int_0^2\int_z^{z+1}dydxdz$. $\:$Since $x$ and $z$ have limits which are constants we take them outside in whatever order. The innermost integral must be the one with variable limits. The limits are $\:0\leq x\leq 2,\:\:0\leq z\leq 4,\:\:z\leq y\leq z+1.$